# Embed youtube video in IOS8 does not fill up Webview width 100%

Tags: webview, youtube, ios8, embed

I have used following code for showing youtube video in iOS.

//Html string to display embed youtube video in native webview

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
                    <html><head>\
                    <style type=\"text/css\">\
                    body {\
                    background-color: transparent; background:none;\
                    }\
                    </style>\
                    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                    <embed src=\"%@\"\
                    type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                    </body></html>";
                    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, http,viewRect.size.width, (viewRect.size.height*-1)];
                    videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewRect.origin.x , (viewRect.origin.y + viewRect.size.height), viewRect.size.width, (viewRect.size.height*-1))];
                    videoView.delegate = self;

                    //Stop Image Move
                    [videoView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
                    [self addSubview:videoView];
                    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
                    videoView.opaque = NO;
                    [self bringSubviewToFront:videoView];
```

I have assigned same width and height to both web view and the embed tag.Previously in iOS7, this code works well without any problem. But in iOS8 the youtube video width doesn't fills up the web view.Please I will really be a help, if someone advice on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue did you find a solution for this? Thanks